# How to stop Javascript execution

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing a basic "Rock Paper Scissors" game in JavaScript. When the player (or computer) wins, the game asks the player if they want to play again. When the player says yes, the game starts as usual. However, when the player says "no", the whole script starts over again. I want to set it so that when players say no, the script stops, and players can browse the webpage normally. I've tried searching around stackoverflow, but when I try any suggestions, the script doesn't start at all. Any help?

EDIT: To be clear, I've only tested this on Google Chrome.

CODE:
---START OF CODE---

```
var mywins = 0
var compwins = 0
var x = 'y'

function intro() {
    var name = prompt('What is your name?');
    alert('Hello, ' + name + '!');
    alert('I want to play rock, paper, scissors with you, ' + name + '.');
    alert("Let's begin. NOTE: You will not be able to quit out until you click 'Prevent this website from creating additional dialogues.' in Google Chrome. Other browsers, I don't know.");
    alert("type 's' for scissors, 'r' for rock, and 'p' for paper! The letters need to be lowercase. Typing in any other character will show you the current score. Your score is first, then mine.");
}

function MainLoop() {
    var mywins = 0
    var compwins = 0
    while (compwins < 3 || mywins < 3) {
        var choice = prompt('Your turn!');
        var compchoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        if (choice == 'r' && compchoice == 0) {
            alert("That's a tie!");
        } else if (choice == 'r' && compchoice == 1) {
            alert('I won!');
            compwins = compwins + 1
        } else if (choice == 'r' && compchoice == 2) {
            alert('You won!');
            mywins = mywins + 1
        } else if (choice == 'p' && compchoice == 0) {
            alert('You won!');
            mywins = mywins + 1
        } else if (choice == 'p' && compchoice == 1) {
            alert('Darn! A tie!');
        } else if (choice == 'p' && compchoice == 2) {
            alert('Haha! I picked scissors!');
            compwins = compwins + 1
        } else if (choice == 's' && compchoice == 0) {
            alert('Oh! So sad! I won that round!')
            compwins = compwins + 1
        } else if (choice == 's' && compchoice == 1) {
            alert('Ugh. I guess you won that round...');
            mywins = mywins + 1
        } else if (choice == 's' && compchoice == 2) {
            alert('A tie!')
        }
        alert(mywins + '-' + compwins);
        if (mywins == 3 || compwins == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

function DisplayWin() {
    if (compwins == 3) {
        alert("That's it! Three wins! I won the game! HAHA!");
    } else if (mywins == 3) {
        alert("Crap! you won! Bet you can't beat me TWICE in a row!");
    }
}

function playagain() {
    var x = prompt("Play again? (y) or (n)")
}
if (x === n) return;
```

---END OF CODE---

The `if(x === n) return;` part is what I tried from stackoverflow. Am I even using it correctly?

Comment: ok, but you need to show us the javascript

Comment: return false; or return;

Comment: I'll put that in the question. @AmmarCSE

Comment: There is no generic answer to a generic question like this.  The only possible answer is how to change your code to do what you want.  So, are you expecting us to tell you how to change your code without showing us the code?  Please think for a second about what information people might need in order to be able to help you and include that in your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just put the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just add a prompt to the end of your `MainLoop()` function and the just `break` out of the `while` loop if they user does not want to continue like this:

```
    if (!confirm("Continue to play?")) {
        break;
    }
```

Or, in context in the whole function:

```
function MainLoop() {
    var mywins = 0
    var compwins = 0
    while (compwins < 3 || mywins < 3) {
        var choice = prompt('Your turn!');
        var compchoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        if (choice == 'r' && compchoice == 0) {
            alert("That's a tie!");
        } else if (choice == 'r' && compchoice == 1) {
            alert('I won!');
            compwins = compwins + 1
        } else if (choice == 'r' && compchoice == 2) {
            alert('You won!');
            mywins = mywins + 1
        } else if (choice == 'p' && compchoice == 0) {
            alert('You won!');
            mywins = mywins + 1
        } else if (choice == 'p' && compchoice == 1) {
            alert('Darn! A tie!');
        } else if (choice == 'p' && compchoice == 2) {
            alert('Haha! I picked scissors!');
            compwins = compwins + 1
        } else if (choice == 's' && compchoice == 0) {
            alert('Oh! So sad! I won that round!')
            compwins = compwins + 1
        } else if (choice == 's' && compchoice == 1) {
            alert('Ugh. I guess you won that round...');
            mywins = mywins + 1
        } else if (choice == 's' && compchoice == 2) {
            alert('A tie!')
        }
        alert(mywins + '-' + compwins);
        if (mywins == 3 || compwins == 3) {
            break;
        }
        if (!confirm("Continue to play?")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @nhanley19 - I showed you exactly where it goes in `MainLoop()` so I don't understand what else you're asking.

Comment: I tried putting it into my .js file, but it wouldn't run the script. I guess I wasn't asking the right question!